# AST transforms not working with groovy eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, groovy, metaprogramming

I wrote a simple AST transform to add logging around annotated methods.  It correctly adds logging around methods when I compile my program with `groovyc` on the command line.  However, it doesn't have any effect when I compile my program in eclipse with the groovy eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working.  What version of the plugin are you using?  First, I'd recommend upgrading to the 2.1.1 release to see if that works.

Also, I'd recommend opening the Groovy Event Console (http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+2.1.1+New+and+Noteworthy#Groovy-Eclipse2.1.1NewandNoteworthy-GroovyEventConsole) and seeing what event occur during compilation.  AST transforms should be logged during compiles.

If nothing seems to help, can you attach the source code here?  Better, can you zip up the Eclipse project and attach it to a bug report on http://jira.codehaus.org/GRECLIPSE?

EDIT

As described in the bug report, it appears that the AST transform was not properly created.
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-939

Comment: I zipped my project and attached it to a bug report. Here is the link: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-939